# EF core line group by many to many

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got a many to many relationship table where I'm trying to display a list of reports in a table.

My table looks like this:

Reports Table:

```
Id| ReportName |
1 | report 1   |
2 | report 2   |
3 | report 3   |
```

Report Category Table:

```
Id| Name     |
1 | General  |
2 | Specific |
```

ReportMapping Junction Table:

```
Id| ReportId | CategoryId |
1 | 1        | 1          |
2 | 1        | 2          |
3 | 2        | 1          |
4 | 2        | 2          |
```

Reports can have multiple categories in this example it's just 2 but there could be many more like lets say 1 report can have 5 categories like General, Specific, Test2, Test3, and Test4

I'd like to display a format on a table/list on my .net core application something along the lines of:

```
ReportId| Report Name | Report Categories
1       | report 1    | General, Specific
2       | report 2    | General, Specific
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work in both sql server and in EF core linq. Any pointers on how to start this out? So far I'm able to join the tables together but have no idea how to concatenate my results into one row for reports that have multiple categories. I'm getting things like below instead of my desired result like the above example:

```
ReportId | Report Name | Report Categories
1        | report 1    | General
1        | report 1    | Specific
2        | report 2    | General
2        | report 2    | Specific
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model your are describing is nearly identical to the `Post` / `Tag` model from [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) example in EF Core documentation.

So you would have 3 classes representing the table records

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReportMapping> Mappings { get; set; }  // navigation
}

public class ReportCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReportMapping> Mappings { get; set; } // navigation
}

public class ReportMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Report Report { get; set; } // navigation
    public ReportCategory Category { get; set; } // navigation
}
```

and 3 `DbSet`s representing your tables:

```
public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
public DbSet<ReportCategory> ReportCategories { get; set; }
public DbSet<ReportMapping> ReportMappings { get; set; }
```

Note that `Id` property(column) in the junction entity(table) is redundant, so in case you are not constrained to an existing database, consider removing it and configure composite PK as in the example

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ReportMapping>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.ReportId, e.CategoryId });
```

Also note the properties marked with `// navigation`. These are the so called *navigation properties* (see [Definition of Terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#definition-of-terms)), which represent the ends of the relationships, and allow you to access the related data inside LINQ queries 
without using `join` constructs - see [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) and is the EF (Core) recommended/preferred way of writing LINQ queries.

So this is your database model. Since you want a query returning specific result type, start by defining a class which represents that result (a.k.a. DTO, ViewModel etc.), for instance:

```
public class ReportInfo
{
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ReportCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I'm defining the `ReportCategories` as sequence of strings rather than single string. This is because first, string concatenation of a result set is not natively supported by the databases, and second, concatenating with comma is just one of the many ways this data can be presented. In general formatting of the data is responsibility of the clients. So you return the data in its raw native format (list of strings) and let the client format it (in this case, it can do that easily by using `string.Join(",", info.ReportCategories)`).

Finally, the actual query. With navigation properties in place it's quite simple - basically just `Select`s:

```
var result = db.Reports
    .Select(r => new ReportInfo
    {
        ReportId = r.Id,
        ReportName = r.ReportName,
        ReportCategories = r.Mappings
            .Select(m => m.Category.Name)
            .ToList() // <-- to avoid N + 1 subquery in EF Core 2.1+
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ah thank you very much your explanation is very clear too.